# Uncaught exception 'PHP mailer Exception' with message SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'phpmailerException' with message
>   'SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\muhasibb\epaper\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php:1465
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\muhasibb\epaper\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php(1301):
>   PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Tue, 17 O...', 'This is Yousaf ...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\muhasibb\epaper\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php(1181):
>   PHPMailer->postSend() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\muhasibb\epaper\1.php(33):
>   PHPMailer->send() #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\muhasibb\epaper\PHPMailer-master\class.phpmailer.php
>   on line 1465

while  i am using code

```
<?php 
                            // Passing `true` enables exceptions

    //Server settings

    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                                // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                     // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'yousaf.farooq906@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '********';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('yousaf.farooq906@gmail.com', 'Yousaf Farooq');
    $mail->addAddress('yousaf.farooq906@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional


    //Attachments
        // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Yousaf Farooq';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is Yousaf Farooq';


    if($mail->send())
    echo 'Message has been sent';
    else
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
?>
```

Comment: [Try setting `SMTPDebug` to 3 to see connection details](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: Since you've asked it to throw exceptions (by passing `true` to the constructor), it might be a good idea to try catching them too. You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, and have not based your code on the gmail example provided with it which does not make these mistakes.

Comment: Most of this is covered in the troubleshooting guide that the error message links to.

Answer (score 2):

try setting your

`$mail->SMTPSecure`

to

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Also, create app password for your google account and use it in exchange for your password in `$mail->Password`.

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // create a new object
```

I commented this line
    //$mail->isSMTP(); // enable SMTP

```
 $mail->SMTPDebug = 4; 
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
```

You have to use tls whith port 587

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
 $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
 $mail->Port = 587; 
 $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
 $mail->isHTML(true);
 $mail->Username = "yourmail@gmail.com";
 $mail->Password = "yourpassword";
 $mail->From="yourmail@gmail.com";
 $mail->FromName="YOUR NAME";
 $mail->Subject = $subject;
 $mail->Body = $body;
 $mail->addAddress("somemail@gmail.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
   echo "Email Sent";
 }
```

Also when you are using gmail you go to Apps with account access and set Allow less secure apps: ON

[GMAIL CONFIGURATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oskjS.png)

Answer (score -1):

If working in localhost,

In php.ini:  remove the semicolon in front of "sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost" and restart xampp.

In  gmail account: in the security settings,  turn on "Allow less secure apps".

And finally in  PHP script:  add two functions:
"date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC')"
"gethostbyname('ssl://smtp.gmail.com')" as a value for " $mail->Host"

Comment: 1) this has nothing to do with php.ini settings as it's using direct SMTP; 2) bad advice, not necessary - read the PHPMailer docs; 3) will break if you're using IPv6, and is the wrong syntax for `gethostbyname`. Apart from all that, just great :)