# PHPMailer allows mime boundary to be visible

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send email via smtp-relay.gmail.com - [see previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54622701/php-trying-to-send-mail-securely-cannot-find-the-phpmailer-class) After making an account through G-Suite, my credentials are being accept, but when the email is delivered, I can see the plain text version, as well as, the html version, with some other characters along the way:

```
    ------example.com----250cd4bbb8be52d828379181e485c269 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit Order Received
```

...

```
 ------example.com----250cd4bbb8be52d828379181e485c269 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
```

Followed by the html version, that ends with the following:

```
------example.com----250cd4bbb8be52d828379181e485c269--
```

When I was using the vanilla version, it worked just fine without seeing the plain text or the mime boundary data:

```
$send = mail($recpEmails, $subject, $htmlMessage, $headers);
```

The variable $htmlMessage still holds the same information as before, but now PHPMailer is sending it via the following line:

```
$mail->Body = $htmlMessage;
```

I would not see the plain text or these other lines with the dashes. Why would sending via PHPMailer > smtp-relay.gmail.com change the results?

Is it because I added the following line?

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Is it due to the following line and, if so, then what should I set it to?

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
```

Are there configurations in the G-Suite> email> advanced settings that I need to change?

Here is the updated code from the previous post:

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->Host = "smtp-relay.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = "587";
  $mail->Username = "info@example.com";
  $mail->Password = "somePassword";
  $mail->setFrom("info@example.com");
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->Body = $htmlMessage;
  $mail->addAddress($recpEmails);
  $mail->Send();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats in `$htmlMessage`?

Comment: @tkausl $htmlMessage, has too much to post here, but basically here is a snippet -   $plain_text = " Order Received"; $plain_text .= "Thank you for your order $user_id,\r\n"; $htmlMessage = "--$mime_boundary\n";
  $htmlMessage .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n";
  $htmlMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
  $htmlMessage .= "$plain_text\n";  $htmlMessage .= "<p style='padding:30px 0 0 0;margin:0;'> &nbsp;<br />"; etc...

Comment: So you literally get what you are telling PHPMailer to send. You're not supposed to build the message yourself, thats PHPMailers job to do.

Comment: @tkausl, yes, you are correct and I believe I have just found the answer in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507176/send-html-and-plain-text-email-simultaneously-with-php-mailer - I am not supposed to build the boundary as I have to do with PHP's mail. Instead, I should just do $mail->AltBody  =  $textMessage; for the text portion and PHPMailer will create the boundary for me. I will change my code followed by testing. If I am successful, then I will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the answer is in the following [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507176/send-html-and-plain-text-email-simultaneously-with-php-mailer)

I used to build the mime boundary between the text only and html version via PHP's mail in the following way:

Create the text message - this should be exactly the same as your html to avoid being marked as spam:

```
$plain_text = ""; // same words that will appear in the html
```

Start creating the mime boundary:

```
# -=-=-=- MIME BOUNDARY
$mime_boundary = "----example.com----".md5(time());
# -=-=-=- MAIL HEADERS
```

Create the subject:

```
$subject = "example.com\n";
```

Create the headers, which will include the mime boundary that you began earlier. As well as, **adding the plain text message in the header - in between the first mime boundary**:

```
$headers = "From: example.com <cs@example.com>\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: example.com <cs@example.com>\n";
$headers .= "BCC: example.com <info@example.com>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";

$htmlMessage = "--$mime_boundary\n";
$htmlMessage .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii\n";
$htmlMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n";
$htmlMessage .= "$plain_text\n";

$htmlMessage .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
$htmlMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
$htmlMessage .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
$htmlMessage .= "<html>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "<body>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "" // has to be the same words as the plain text to avoid being marked as spam
$htmlMessage .= "</body>\n";
$htmlMessage .= "</html>\n";
```

Complete the mime boundary:

```
# -=-=-=- FINAL BOUNDARY
$htmlMessage .= "--$mime_boundary--\n\n";
# -=-=-=- SEND MAIL
```

However, with PHPMailer all of this code is no longer necessary by using the following two lines of code:

```
  $mail->AltBody = $plain_text; 
  $mail->Body = $htmlMessage;
```

The following is what I have tested and use:

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 3; 
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
  $mail->Host = "smtp-relay.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = "587";
  $mail->Username = "cs@example.com";
  $mail->Password = "somePassword";
  $mail->setFrom("cs@example.com");
  $mail->isHTML(true);
  $mail->Subject = $subject;
  $mail->AltBody = $plain_text; 
  $mail->Body = $htmlMessage;
  $mail->addAddress($recpEmails);
  $mail->Send();
```

Almost forgot, but this is how I added BCC:

```
  $mail->addBCC("info@example.com");
```